# PHP: How to calculate the max. number of permutation

Tags: php

Let say I have some variables containing different numbers:

```
$element_a =1;
$element_b =1;
$element_c =7;
$element_d =8;
$element_e =15;
$element_f =7;
$element_g =7;
```

and the script choose a random number for each var:

```
$element_a = rand (1, $element_a);
$element_b = rand (1, $element_b);
$element_c = rand (1, $element_c);
$element_d= rand (1, $element_d);
$element_e= rand (1, $element_e);
$element_f= rand (1, $element_f);
$element_g= rand (1, $element_g);
```

and now, all this elements generate a situation,

how can i calculate how many different situations are possible?

Comment: any one have a clue what is being asked here?

Comment: `$element_a * $element_b * $element_c * $element_d * $element_e * $element_f * $element_g`

Comment: It's basic math btw

Comment: Might be worth reading: http://stattrek.com/online-calculator/combinations-permutations.aspx and http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/ats5/lcomb.htm

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141302/how-to-find-all-possible-combinations-of-a-set-of-options

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math problem, not programming. It has already been answered on math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: thanks a lot! Sorry for this!